# How can I reproduce the final result of these codes?

Tags: xml

I'm sorry if the title is too general; anyway

this is a portion of a **XML file**:

```
&lt;/dl&gt;&lt;dl&gt;&lt;b&gt;elo·quent&lt;/b&gt; &lt;!--id=000014151--&gt;&lt;i&gt;BrE&lt;/i&gt; &lt;font color=darkgray&gt; &lt;/font&gt;&lt;font color=darkcyan&gt;[ˈeləkwənt]&lt;/font&gt; &lt;i&gt;&amp;nbsp;&lt;/i&gt;&lt;OBJECT CLASSID=&quot;CLSID:6BF52A52-394A-11d3-B153-00C04F79FAA6&quot; type=&quot;application/x-oleobject&quot; width=16 height=12 volume=100&gt;&lt;PARAM NAME=&quot;EnableContextMenu&quot; VALUE=&quot;False&quot;&gt;&lt;PARAM NAME=&quot;AutoStart&quot; VALUE=&quot;False&quot;&gt;&lt;PARAM NAME=&quot;URL&quot; VALUE=&quot;D:\Dictionaries\En-En-OALD8.dsl.files\z_eloquent__gb_1.wav&quot;&gt;&lt;/OBJECT&gt;&lt;i&gt;&amp;nbsp;&lt;/i&gt;
     &lt;i&gt;NAmE&lt;/i&gt; &lt;font color=darkgray&gt; &lt;/font&gt;&lt;font color=darkcyan&gt;[ˈeləkwənt]&lt;/font&gt; &lt;i&gt;&amp;nbsp;&lt;/i&gt;&lt;OBJECT CLASSID=&quot;CLSID:6BF52A52-394A-11d3-B153-00C04F79FAA6&quot; type=&quot;application/x-oleobject&quot; width=16 height=12 volume=100&gt;&lt;PARAM NAME=&quot;EnableContextMenu&quot; VALUE=&quot;False&quot;&gt;&lt;PARAM NAME=&quot;AutoStart&quot; VALUE=&quot;False&quot;&gt;&lt;PARAM NAME=&quot;URL&quot; VALUE=&quot;D:\Dictionaries\En-En-OALD8.dsl.files\z_eloquent__us_1.wav&quot;&gt;&lt;/OBJECT&gt;&lt;i&gt;&amp;nbsp;&lt;/i&gt;
     &lt;font color=orange&gt; adjective&lt;/font&gt;&lt;br&gt;
&lt;/dt&gt;&lt;dt&gt;&lt;font color=darkmagenta&gt;&lt;b&gt;1.&lt;/b&gt;&lt;/font&gt; &lt;!--d--&gt;able to use language and express your opinions well, especially when you are speaking in public&lt;!--/d--&gt;&lt;br&gt;
&lt;dd&gt;&lt;font color=forestgreen&gt;• &lt;/font&gt;&lt;font color=forestgreen&gt;&lt;!--x--&gt;an &lt;!--/x--&gt; &lt;/font&gt;&lt;b&gt;&lt;font color=darkslategray&gt;&lt;!--cl--&gt;eloquent speech/speaker&lt;!--/cl--&gt; &lt;/font&gt;&lt;/b&gt;&lt;br&gt;
&lt;/dt&gt;&lt;dt&gt;&lt;font color=darkmagenta&gt;&lt;b&gt;2.&lt;/b&gt;&lt;/font&gt; &lt;font color=darkgray&gt;(&lt;/font&gt;&lt;font color=darkslategray&gt;&lt;i&gt;&lt;!--dc--&gt;of a look or movement&lt;!--/dc--&gt;&lt;/i&gt;&lt;/font&gt;&lt;font color=darkgray&gt;) &lt;/font&gt;&lt;!--d--&gt;able to express a feeling&lt;!--/d--&gt;&lt;br&gt;
&lt;dd&gt;&lt;font color=forestgreen&gt;• &lt;/font&gt;&lt;font color=forestgreen&gt;&lt;!--x--&gt;His eyes were eloquent.&lt;!--/x--&gt; &lt;/font&gt;&lt;font color=darkgray&gt; &lt;/font&gt;&lt;br&gt;
    &lt;!--Derived Word--&gt;&lt;dd&gt;&lt;font color=darkslategray&gt;&lt;u&gt;Derived Words:&lt;/u&gt;&lt;/font&gt; &lt;font color=gray size=0.1&gt;↑ &lt;/font&gt;&lt;font color=blue&gt;eloquence&lt;/font&gt; &lt;font color=darkslategray&gt;&lt;b&gt;▪&lt;/b&gt;&lt;/font&gt; &lt;font color=gray size=0.1&gt;↑ &lt;/font&gt;&lt;font color=blue&gt;eloquently&lt;/font&gt;&lt;!--/Derived Word--&gt; &lt;dd&gt; &lt;br&gt;
    &lt;!--Word Origin--&gt;&lt;dd&gt;&lt;font color=darkslategray&gt;&lt;u&gt;Word Origin:&lt;/u&gt;&lt;/font&gt;&lt;br&gt;
&lt;dd&gt; &lt;font color=rosybrown&gt;[&lt;/font&gt;&lt;font color=darkslategray&gt;&lt;b&gt;eloquence&lt;/b&gt;&lt;/font&gt; &lt;font color=darkslategray&gt;&lt;b&gt;eloquent&lt;/b&gt;&lt;/font&gt; &lt;font color=darkslategray&gt;&lt;b&gt;eloquently&lt;/b&gt;&lt;/font&gt;&lt;font color=rosybrown&gt;]&lt;/font&gt; &lt;font color=darkgray&gt; &lt;/font&gt;&lt;font color=darkslategray&gt;&lt;!--lang--&gt;late Middle English&lt;!--/lang--&gt;&lt;/font&gt;&lt;font color=dimgray&gt;&lt;!--etymology--&gt;: via &lt;!--/etymology--&gt; &lt;/font&gt;&lt;font color=darkslategray&gt;&lt;!--lang--&gt;Old French&lt;!--/lang--&gt; &lt;/font&gt;&lt;font color=dimgray&gt;&lt;!--etymology--&gt; from &lt;!--/etymology--&gt; &lt;/font&gt;&lt;font color=darkslategray&gt;&lt;!--lang--&gt;Latin&lt;!--/lang--&gt; &lt;/font&gt;&lt;font color=darkgray&gt; &lt;/font&gt;&lt;font color=darkcyan&gt;&lt;!--ff--&gt;eloquent-&lt;!--/ff--&gt; &lt;/font&gt;&lt;font color=darkgray&gt; &lt;/font&gt;&lt;font color=darkslateblue&gt;&lt;b&gt;&lt;!--etym_tr--&gt;‘speaking out’&lt;!--/etym_tr--&gt;&lt;/b&gt;&lt;/font&gt;&lt;font color=dimgray&gt;&lt;!--etymology--&gt;, from the verb &lt;!--/etymology--&gt; &lt;/font&gt;&lt;font color=darkcyan&gt;&lt;!--ff--&gt;eloqui&lt;!--/ff--&gt; &lt;/font&gt;&lt;font color=darkgray&gt; &lt;/font&gt;&lt;font color=darkslateblue&gt;&lt;b&gt;&lt;!--etym_tr--&gt;‘speak out’&lt;!--/etym_tr--&gt;&lt;/b&gt;&lt;/font&gt;&lt;font color=dimgray&gt;&lt;!--etymology--&gt;, from &lt;!--/etymology--&gt; &lt;/font&gt;&lt;font color=darkcyan&gt;&lt;!--ff--&gt;e-&lt;!--/ff--&gt; &lt;/font&gt;&lt;font color=dimgray&gt;&lt;!--etymology--&gt; (variant of &lt;!--/etymology--&gt; &lt;/font&gt;&lt;font color=darkcyan&gt;&lt;!--ff--&gt;ex-&lt;!--/ff--&gt;&lt;/font&gt;&lt;font color=dimgray&gt;&lt;!--etymology--&gt;) &lt;!--/etymology--&gt; &lt;/font&gt;&lt;font color=darkslateblue&gt;&lt;b&gt;&lt;!--etym_tr--&gt;‘out’&lt;!--/etym_tr--&gt; &lt;/b&gt;&lt;/font&gt;&lt;font color=dimgray&gt;&lt;!--etymology--&gt; + &lt;!--/etymology--&gt; &lt;/font&gt;&lt;font color=darkcyan&gt;&lt;!--ff--&gt;loqui&lt;!--/ff--&gt; &lt;/font&gt;&lt;font color=darkgray&gt; &lt;/font&gt;&lt;font color=darkslateblue&gt;&lt;b&gt;&lt;!--etym_tr--&gt;‘speak’&lt;!--/etym_tr--&gt;&lt;/b&gt;&lt;/font&gt;&lt;font color=dimgray&gt;&lt;!--etymology--&gt;.&lt;!--/etymology--&gt; &lt;/font&gt; &lt;dd&gt; &lt;br&gt;
    &lt;!--Example Bank--&gt;&lt;dd&gt;&lt;font color=darkslategray&gt;&lt;u&gt;Example Bank:&lt;/u&gt;&lt;/font&gt;&lt;br&gt;
&lt;dd&gt;&lt;font color=forestgreen&gt;• &lt;/font&gt;&lt;font color=forestgreen&gt;&lt;!--x--&gt;He grew very eloquent on the subject.&lt;!--/x--&gt; &lt;/font&gt;&lt;br&gt;
&lt;dd&gt;&lt;font color=forestgreen&gt;• &lt;/font&gt;&lt;font color=darkgray&gt; &lt;/font&gt;&lt;font color=forestgreen&gt;&lt;!--x--&gt;He waxed eloquent about her talents as an actress.&lt;!--/x--&gt; &lt;/font&gt;&lt;br&gt;
&lt;dd&gt;&lt;font color=forestgreen&gt;• &lt;/font&gt;&lt;font color=darkgray&gt; &lt;/font&gt;&lt;font color=forestgreen&gt;&lt;!--x--&gt;a very eloquent speaker&lt;!--/x--&gt; &lt;/font&gt;&lt;br&gt;
&lt;dd&gt;&lt;font color=forestgreen&gt;• &lt;/font&gt;&lt;font color=darkgray&gt; &lt;/font&gt;&lt;font color=forestgreen&gt;&lt;!--x--&gt;It was an eloquent and well-informed speech.&lt;!--/x--&gt; &lt;/font&gt;&lt;br&gt;
&lt;dd&gt;&lt;font color=forestgreen&gt;• &lt;/font&gt;&lt;font color=darkgray&gt; &lt;/font&gt;&lt;font color=forestgreen&gt;&lt;!--x--&gt;She was an eloquent speaker, with a beautiful voice.&lt;!--/x--&gt; &lt;/font&gt;
```

the result of this codes is this: (in Babylon(word translator)):
[image]
**My question is: how can I reproduce the final look of the code (as in picture)?** I mean may be it's an html code, and if I open it in a browser, I reproduce the final results(I did it without success)

Comment: This is not XML, it's HTML. XML's node attributes aren't like this `color=forestgreen`

Comment: As has been said earlier it's not XML, its encoded html. Try this Decoder: http://www.opinionatedgeek.com/DotNet/Tools/HTMLEncode/Decode.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code is HTML encoded with HTML entities. You would have to decode all the entities. Then the code can be shown as HTML in a browser.

Answer (score 0):

```
</dl><dl><b>elo·quent</b> <!--id=000014151--><i>BrE</i> <font color=darkgray> </font><font color=darkcyan>[ˈeləkwənt]</font> <i>&amp;nbsp;</i><OBJECT CLASSID="CLSID:6BF52A52-394A-11d3-B153-00C04F79FAA6" type="application/x-oleobject" width=16 height=12 volume=100><PARAM NAME="EnableContextMenu" VALUE="False"><PARAM NAME="AutoStart" VALUE="False"><PARAM NAME="URL" VALUE="D:\Dictionaries\En-En-OALD8.dsl.files\z_eloquent__gb_1.wav"></OBJECT><i>&amp;nbsp;</i>
     <i>NAmE</i> <font color=darkgray> </font><font color=darkcyan>[ˈeləkwənt]</font> <i>&amp;nbsp;</i><OBJECT CLASSID="CLSID:6BF52A52-394A-11d3-B153-00C04F79FAA6" type="application/x-oleobject" width=16 height=12 volume=100><PARAM NAME="EnableContextMenu" VALUE="False"><PARAM NAME="AutoStart" VALUE="False"><PARAM NAME="URL" VALUE="D:\Dictionaries\En-En-OALD8.dsl.files\z_eloquent__us_1.wav"></OBJECT><i>&amp;nbsp;</i>
     <font color=orange> adjective</font><br>
</dt><dt><font color=darkmagenta><b>1.</b></font> <!--d-->able to use language and express your opinions well, especially when you are speaking in public<!--/d--><br>
<dd><font color=forestgreen>• </font><font color=forestgreen><!--x-->an <!--/x--> </font><b><font color=darkslategray><!--cl-->eloquent speech/speaker<!--/cl--> </font></b><br>
</dt><dt><font color=darkmagenta><b>2.</b></font> <font color=darkgray>(</font><font color=darkslategray><i><!--dc-->of a look or movement<!--/dc--></i></font><font color=darkgray>) </font><!--d-->able to express a feeling<!--/d--><br>
<dd><font color=forestgreen>• </font><font color=forestgreen><!--x-->His eyes were eloquent.<!--/x--> </font><font color=darkgray> </font><br>
    <!--Derived Word--><dd><font color=darkslategray><u>Derived Words:</u></font> <font color=gray size=0.1>↑ </font><font color=blue>eloquence</font> <font color=darkslategray><b>▪</b></font> <font color=gray size=0.1>↑ </font><font color=blue>eloquently</font><!--/Derived Word--> <dd> <br>
    <!--Word Origin--><dd><font color=darkslategray><u>Word Origin:</u></font><br>
<dd> <font color=rosybrown>[</font><font color=darkslategray><b>eloquence</b></font> <font color=darkslategray><b>eloquent</b></font> <font color=darkslategray><b>eloquently</b></font><font color=rosybrown>]</font> <font color=darkgray> </font><font color=darkslategray><!--lang-->late Middle English<!--/lang--></font><font color=dimgray><!--etymology-->: via <!--/etymology--> </font><font color=darkslategray><!--lang-->Old French<!--/lang--> </font><font color=dimgray><!--etymology--> from <!--/etymology--> </font><font color=darkslategray><!--lang-->Latin<!--/lang--> </font><font color=darkgray> </font><font color=darkcyan><!--ff-->eloquent-<!--/ff--> </font><font color=darkgray> </font><font color=darkslateblue><b><!--etym_tr-->‘speaking out’<!--/etym_tr--></b></font><font color=dimgray><!--etymology-->, from the verb <!--/etymology--> </font><font color=darkcyan><!--ff-->eloqui<!--/ff--> </font><font color=darkgray> </font><font color=darkslateblue><b><!--etym_tr-->‘speak out’<!--/etym_tr--></b></font><font color=dimgray><!--etymology-->, from <!--/etymology--> </font><font color=darkcyan><!--ff-->e-<!--/ff--> </font><font color=dimgray><!--etymology--> (variant of <!--/etymology--> </font><font color=darkcyan><!--ff-->ex-<!--/ff--></font><font color=dimgray><!--etymology-->) <!--/etymology--> </font><font color=darkslateblue><b><!--etym_tr-->‘out’<!--/etym_tr--> </b></font><font color=dimgray><!--etymology--> + <!--/etymology--> </font><font color=darkcyan><!--ff-->loqui<!--/ff--> </font><font color=darkgray> </font><font color=darkslateblue><b><!--etym_tr-->‘speak’<!--/etym_tr--></b></font><font color=dimgray><!--etymology-->.<!--/etymology--> </font> <dd> <br>
    <!--Example Bank--><dd><font color=darkslategray><u>Example Bank:</u></font><br>
<dd><font color=forestgreen>• </font><font color=forestgreen><!--x-->He grew very eloquent on the subject.<!--/x--> </font><br>
<dd><font color=forestgreen>• </font><font color=darkgray> </font><font color=forestgreen><!--x-->He waxed eloquent about her talents as an actress.<!--/x--> </font><br>
<dd><font color=forestgreen>• </font><font color=darkgray> </font><font color=forestgreen><!--x-->a very eloquent speaker<!--/x--> </font><br>
<dd><font color=forestgreen>• </font><font color=darkgray> </font><font color=forestgreen><!--x-->It was an eloquent and well-informed speech.<!--/x--> </font><br>
<dd><font color=forestgreen>• </font><font color=darkgray> </font><font color=forestgreen><!--x-->She was an eloquent speaker, with a beautiful voice.<!--/x--> </font>
```

see also:

http://www.htmlhelp.com/reference/html40/entities/special.html
http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_entities.asp